# How to manipulate Standard Industry field with Data Loader?

Tags: custom-object, data-loader, picklist, standard-objects

History:

We created a new Industry__c field under Account, in order to be able to have multiselect option on the 35 picklists values.

Now, it is requested that we will only have 6 options, and NO multi select.

I want to move back to the Standard object.

I am unable to either Export or Update the Standard field: Industry  - It's not visible in the data loader filter options.

[image]

How can I update the Standard Object : Industry , with the new values?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, easy solution:

The field was Hidden from my profile (System Administrator) - Change the fields visibility to View - and you can see it in the Dataloader.